# Add items on listbox if it doesn't exist based on checkbox

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add an item  to a listbox if the item does not exist in the list and remove that Item based on whether that checkbox is checked or unchecked.

I'm at the point of trying to add to the list if the item does not exist

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

If Me.CheckBox1.Value Then
    For Each doc In Me.DocsList.List
        If Me.TextBox7.Text <> doc Then
            Me.DocsList.AddItem (Me.TextBox7.Text)
        End If
    Next doc
End If
End Sub
```

for some reasons I'm not able to add anything. I can add without the loop though

Comment: doc is not an object so doesn't have a Value property, also you should declare doc as Variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to loop, this code will add the value from TextBox7 to the listbox if it isn't already listed.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
Dim items As Variant
Dim Res As Variant

    If Me.DocsList.ListCount = 0 Then
      Me.DocsList.List = Array(Me.TextBox7.Text)
      Exit Sub
    End If
    
    items = Me.DocsList.List
    Res = Application.Match(Me.TextBox7.Text, items, 0)

    If Me.CheckBox1.Value Then
        If IsError(Res) Then
            Me.DocsList.AddItem Me.TextBox7.Text
        End If
    ElseIf Not IsError(Res) Then
        Me.DocsList.RemoveItem Res - 1
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how would you got about removing that item if the checkbox is unchecked?

Comment: I get application mismatch on variable res :/

Comment: What's in the textbox when you get the error? Did you change anything in the code I posted?

Comment: no I changed no code. The listbox has the value of textbox7.text. It's the only thing in there

Comment: I can't replicate the problem, when the listbox has only one item and the value in the textbox is the same as the item the code works as required. Is there anything else going on? How many columns are in the listbox?

Comment: I'm not sure either, it only has 1 column and contains textbox7's value. I'm on office 365 maybe they changed something

Comment: I see what the issue is. Application.match is receiving incorrect arguments. I think you meant to use application.worksheetfunction.match arguments

Comment: No, I meant to us Application.Match - if you use Application.WorksheetFunction.Match and a match wasn't found it would cause a run-time error.

Comment: OK i think that's what's happening. For some reason it didn't find a match and keeps throwing an error. :/

Comment: If a match isn't found an error shouldn't be thrown, that's why Application.Match is used instead of Application.WorksheetFunction.Match. Where are you actually getting the error? Is it when you are trying to remove or add an tiem?

Comment: It stops at the "Res" variable assignment. Here Res = Application.Match(Me.TextBox7.Text, items, 0)

Comment: I've finally been able to reproduce the error - it only occurs under specific circumstances, e.g when you start out with the listbox completely empty. I've updated the code to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

`List` property does not return a collection able to be iterated in the way you try.

Please, test the next code:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
 Dim i As Long, boolFound As Boolean

 If Me.CheckBox1.value Then
    For i = 0 To Me.docsList.ListCount - 1
        'check the string existence in the list box:
        If Me.TextBox7.Text = Me.docsList.list(i) Then
            boolFound = True: Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    If Not boolFound Then Me.docsList.AddItem Me.TextBox7.Text
 End If
End Sub
```